# Finding a function with some specific properties

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm looking for an analytical expression of a function that would have a certain kind of behavior:

- $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow + \infty}f(x)=+\infty$ (or at least $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow B'>B}f(x)=+ \infty $)
- $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow - \infty}f(x)=+\infty$ (or at least $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow A'<0}f(x)= + \infty$)
- Two inflection points $a,b$ with $a<b,f''(a)=f''(b)=0$
- Two points with the same derivative $A,B$ with $A<a<b<B$, $f'(A)=f'(B) \geq 0$
- $A,B>0$

Like here : 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=(x-2)^4+3(x-2)^3+2(x-2)^2+1$ seems to fulfill those criteria.

Expanding all those terms and simplifying, that equation becomes $$f(x)=x^4-5x^2+8x^2-4x+1$$

[image]

Comment: To shift the function $a$ units to the right, you replace $x$ in the equation by $(x-a)$. I saw from your illustration that the function you were looking for was most likely a fourth-degree polynomial (from the number of turning points), and then I played around with the coefficients in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) until I found a function that worked.